Snowflake Kafka Connector private keys environmental variables unable to decrypt
I currently have my snowflake connector configuration set in a JSON file
{
  "name": "connector-name",
  "config": {
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "connector.class":"com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
"snowflake.url.name":"$URL",
"snowflake.user.name":"$USERNAME",
"snowflake.schema.name":"$SCHEMA",
"snowflake.database.name":"$DB_NAME",
"snowflake.private.key":"$PRIVATE_KEY",
"snowflake.private.key.passphrase":"$PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE",
"snowflake.topic2table.map":"topic:table",
"snowflake.ingestion.method":"snowpipe_streaming",
"snowflake.role.name":"RW",
"topics":"topic"
}
}

Then I have my script to post
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @<path>/<config_file>.json http://localhost:8083/connectors

To read the environmental variables from "${PRIVATE_KEY}" and other environmental variables to "'"$PRIVATE_KEY"'" I did a sed
format_value = printf '&s\n' "$value" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'
sed -i 's/$PRIVATE_KEY/'"$format_private_key"'/g' $json_file

However when I ran the POST call, I get the following error
("error_code":400, "message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):\nsnowflake.private.key is not valid\nsnowflake.private.key.passphrase is not valid\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/(connector type)/config/validate`"k

I understand since the private key and private key passphrase have some special characters which cannot be excluded. So what can I do to read my key and passphrase. I am using Kafka connect library so it should be automatically decrypted. I hardcoded the values and it worked, but when I used environmental variables in my connector JSON file and it failed to read. I echoed the command and I see my passkey and passphrase correct, but i do not understand why it cannot be decrypted or unable to read properly. Can someone help.
Do I need to configure as
"snowflake.private.key":"{{env_var($PRIVATE_KEY)}}"?

or do I need to word the environmental variables in a certain way?
